Confusion about the use of VC in SVMs
For linear separators in $d$ dimensions, we have
$d_{VC}(\rho) \le d_{VC}(0) =d+1$ where $\rho$ is the margin.
Based on the above result, does that mean SVM consistently produces a classifier
with superior generalization performance compared to any linear separator derived from the Perceptron Learning Algorithm (PLA), as PLA does not maximize the separation margin between classes?

Can you clarify what $d_{VC}(p)$ means? VC probably stands for the VC dimension, but can you describe function and number? I suppose that's the VC dimension of some function of an SVM, but please put that into words. Also, where did you take this formula from?

SVM looks to maximize the margin $ρ$ of support vectors to reduce the model's effective complexity for overfitting and improves its generalization ability. The bound $d_{VC}(ρ)≤d_{VC}(0)$ shows that while both SVM and PLA may have the same VC dimension for linear separators in worst case scenarios, the margin maximization in SVM effectively reduces its VC-dimension on average compared to PLA, making it a better choice for generalization.
